# Sum all the rows excluding top 2

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table like:

[image]

I need to group these rows into 3 rows only, where first two rows in resultset will be top two values and rest of the rows need to be combined into one with sum(values). Result would look like-

| Code | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 17 | 1 |
| 19 | 0 |
| Rest | 0 |

I tried row number with partition, SUM(value) with OVER and some conventional step by step approach which is lots of inefficient code.
Is there a way to do that in SQL Server?

Comment: Do you have another column which has a PROPER SEQUENCE? Identity or datetime ?

Comment: @JohnCappelletti Yes, A PK Identity is there other than these two columns.

Comment: Why is 17 concidered first and 15 last?

Comment: @Lennart-SlavaUkraini It doesn't matter, MAX of Value is the criteria to decide top two and rest should be combined into one.

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I get it right, you can first enumerate using row_number()

```
SELECT code, value, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY value DESC) AS rn
FROM t
```

Now you can use rn in a CASE expression

```
SELECT CASE WHEN rn < 3 THEN CAST(code AS VARCHAR(10)) ELSE 'Rest' END
     , SUM(VALUE)
FROM (
    SELECT code, value, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY value DESC) AS rn
    FROM t
) AS tmp
GROUP BY CASE WHEN rn < 3 THEN CAST(code AS VARCHAR(10)) ELSE 'Rest' END
```

This is of course non-deterministic, but according to your comment that does not matter

Comment: Thank you @Lennart - Slava Ukraini. I was trying exactly that right now :) but failing. Thanks for your help!

Comment: For future posts, make sure to include create table and insert statements or use a https://dbfiddle.uk/ and include the url